# Merge ascii char using C

Tags: c, char, decimal, ascii, bit

[image]

I tried the following code but couldn't get the desired output.
Result should be `AB` and it should come from single variable `C`

````
int main() 
{
  int a = 'A';
  int b = 'B';
  unsigned  int C = a << 8 | b;
  printf(" %c\n",C);
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Please do not post images of code - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please post it as formatted text.

Comment: `%c` will only ever read one char/byte. Do you really need/want to use bit shifting for this? `int C = 'AB'` is not valid code. So it is not clear exactly what is the desired result.

Comment: NOTE: 01000001 is 0x41  Not 0x1000 and   01000010 is 0x42 NOT 0x2000

Comment: regarding: `int a = 'A';
  int b = 'B';`  these should be declared as `unsigned` not `int`

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice!

Comment: @jonathan, the answer wasn't satisfactory and this maybe be quite similar question but it's not.

Comment: @user3229249, the output should be taken out from one variable otherwise i would've done something like ```printf("%c%c", a,b);```

Answer (score 0):

`%c` will print a single character. If you want to print a string, you have to use `%s` and provide a pointer to this string. Strings in C have to be null-terminated, meaning they require one additional character after the text and this character carries the value `\0` (zero).

You could do this in an `int`, but you'd have to understand some concepts first.

If you are using a computer with Intel architecture, integer variables larger than one byte will store data in reverse order in memory. This is called [little-endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

So a number like `0x11223344` (hexadecimal) will be stored in memory as the sequence of bytes `44 33 22 11`.

`'A'` is equivalent to the number 65, or `0x00000041`, and if put in a 32-bit integer will be stored as `41 00 00 00`.

When you do `'A' << 8 | 'B'` you create the number `0x00006566`, but in memory it is actually `66 65 00 00` (equivalent to string `"BA\0\0"`). It's in the opposite order of what you're trying to do, but since it is technically null-terminated, it's a valid string.

You can print this using `sprintf("%s", &C);`

If you're in a big-endian architecture (such as ARM), you will have to work out the null-terminator, but I think I already gave you enough information to figure out what is going on for yourself.

Comment: using ```%s``` giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: You are probably providing an invalid pointer. You have to pass `&C` as parameter (a pointer to `C`), not `C` itself.

Comment: ```#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  int a = 'A';
  int b = 'B';
  unsigned  char C = a << 8 | b;
  printf(" %c",C);
  return 0;
}```

Comment: Again, use `sprintf("%s", &C)` instead.

Answer (score -2):

you're trying to print only single byte located at &C, so depending on if you're machine is little endian you'd get "66" as output or if you're machine is big endian you'd get 0 as output.

Comment: Your answer does not address this part of the question: "Result should be AB and it should come from single variable C"

Comment: I want ```AB``` in the output. Please tell me required changes.

Comment: one way to get AB as output would be to use something like printf("%c%c", *((unsigned char *)&C)+1), C);

Comment: @raqeeb, the output should be taken out from one variable otherwise i would've done something like ```printf("%c%c", a,b);```

Comment: C = b << 8 | a; printf("%s",&C); that would work.

Comment: No it's not working